# .htaccess rewrite rule break string on first & operator

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

this is my code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^public/p-(.*)\&(.*)?$ public/index.php?page=$1.php&$2 [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^public/p-(.*)$ public/index.php?page=$1.php
```

This is the URL

```
http://localhost/riviera/public/p-job-steps&job_id=7&step=1
```

Output is

```
Array ( [page] => job-steps [job_id] => 7.php [step] => 1 )
```

I just want to append ".php" to first parameter

I wasted my 4-5 hours in achieving this target and I do not want to modify url structure of app I'm building. 
Please help someone!

Comment: What happens if you add `QSA` to `[NC,L]` ?

Comment: Server ERROR when i add QSA to [NC,L]

Comment: Try replacing all by `RewriteEngine on RewriteRule ^public/p-(.*)$ public/index.php?page=$1.php [QSA,NC]`

Comment: I got this output... in reverse direction Array ( [page] => job-steps [job_id] => 7 [step] => 1.php )

Comment: Okay wait a little bit I'll try the example on my computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple flag named [QSA](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) that will do all the work for you.

Write in the htaccess the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule public/p-(.*) public/index.php?page=$1.php [NC,QSA,B]
```

I tested it, and it gives:

```
Array
(
    [page] => job-steps.php
    [job_id] => 7
    [step] => 1
)
```

When the url is:

```
http://localhost/riviera/public/p-job-steps?job_id=7&step=1
```

And you should add [B](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b) for security reasons.

Comment: Hey thanks but i  want [page] => job-steps.php as first parameter and whatever after job steps in url should be appended to resultant url

Comment: It gives `[page] => job-steps.php` .

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean by `whatever after job steps in url should be appended to resultant url`

Comment: Okay thanks... it is not working not with my URL structure where '&' is used instead of '?'... but I think i now need to modify my app url structure.... to include '?' replacing '&' character.

Comment: Thank you! :) And I forgot one important thing: the [B](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b) flag ! It's for security.